# Can't access the selected checkbox data

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have an array. I want to display all elements in this array as a  checkbox.  and when I press in checkbox I call the function that displays console with the label selected checkbox, but I can't access to all data in the array  it. I used [react-native-checkbox-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-checkbox-form)

Here is my code:

```
<CheckboxFormX
  style={{ width: 350 - 30 }}
  dataSource={all_national_number}
  itemShowKey="label"
  itemCheckedKey="RNchecked"
  iconSize={16}
  formHorizontal={true}
  labelHorizontal={false}
  labelHorizontal={false}
  onChecked={item => this._onSelect(item)}
/>
```

How can I access all the data in image?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It returns an array of objects. For whatever object you want to get the data from you're going to need to specify its position in the array. For example: if you want the value from the first object you would get it like this: `console.log(item[0].value)` likewise if you want the second objects "value" key you would do the same thing but with a different position in the array: `console.log(item[1].value)`

**UPDATED**: To loop through each item use a forEach on your array in your function.

Passing the item: `onChecked={item => this._onSelect(item)}`

In your onSelect function:

`onSelect(item) { 
item.forEach((item) => console.log(item.value)); 
}`

Comment: yes i tried and success but i want to pass the index in this line `onChecked={item => this._onSelect(item)}`

Comment: Then pass that into your onSelect parameters. `onChecked={item => this._onSelect(item[0].value)}`

Comment: this is loop not single index

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Next time you post a question clarify this is what you are trying to achieve.